# QGIS Saving GPS Track

Tags: qgis, gps, tracklog

I am using QGIS v3.24.3-Tisler and have connected an external USB GPS unit (G-START IV) to my laptop. Through the GPS Panel I am able to connect to the GPS fine and the track log is visible and updates on the screen. **However, I would like to be able to save that track log to a layer but cannot find an option to do this.**

I see there is a 'log file' checkbox at the bottom of the GPS Panel but unfortunately with this checked I am not able to select a file using the button with the three dots on the right - nothing happens when I try and select this button (I do not have the GPS connected when trying to select this). I am not even sure if the 'log file' is what I need as the documentation doesn't provide much information on what the log file actually is.

[image]

Comment: See the digitizing section of the panel with the checkboxes "Automatically ..." : https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_gps/live_GPS_tracking.html#gps-options . You can add features with a layer (line in your case) in editing mode.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a new line vector layer and activate editor. than return in GPS panel and clic on add line, in the top of window. Qgis save the track in the layer just created.